# Post to Sprout Forms plugin from an app or another website

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

Is it possible to post a form to Sprout Forms in Craft 2 from a desktop app or another website?

The AJAX example in the docs mentions this - sproutForms/entries/saveEntry
What would the full URL be?

I did try http://domainname.com/sproutForms/entries/saveEntry but it gives an 404 error.

Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using a hidden `action` input, then `sproutForms/entries/saveEntry` should be correct.  You can see that in the Craft docs here: https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/plugins/controllers.html#posting-to-controller-actions

If you're not using that input, or you're constructing the URL to post to manually, then it will likely be `actions/sproutForms/entries/saveEntry` instead, assuming you have set a custom [actionTrigger](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/config-settings.html#actiontrigger) in your general config.

Comment: How would CSRF support play out in a request to Craft from another website? As far as receiving the data, I expect as long as it comes in the right format, it'd be received fine. However, is there a way to pass a valid csrfToken to Craft in a third-party post request, or anything we have to do within the plugin to work around that?

Comment: Gah, sorry @BenParizek. Glanced over the fact it's about posting to another website/app.  CSRF is tied to session so it'd be difficult.